# getting 503 error when trying to acces localhost php webapp on Fedora 36 and php56

Tags: php, apache, localhost, fedora

so im trying to run my php app located in /var/www/html but im getting this errors, i tried restarting both the php-fpm and httpd services, can somebody tell me what is wrong?

```
[Mon Aug 08 12:44:51.592863 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 37442:tid 37620] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/opt/remi/php56/run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Mon Aug 08 12:44:51.592890 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 37442:tid 37620] [client ::1:38870] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

Comment: Check the directory `/var/opt/remi/php56/run/php-fpm/` exists and the file `www.sock` is inside it.

Comment: How do you install php56 ?
There is nothing older than 7.4 in "remi" repository for F >= 36
(mostly because of compatibility with OpenSSL 3)

Comment: @miBra it does exist in the directory, but the error keeps the same

Comment: Maybe PHP-FPM sock file has incorrect permissions or ownership. in the terminal run `ls -lah /var/opt/remi/php56/run/php-fpm/` to check who is the owner of `www.sock` file. `root` or an integer id?